# How can I rewrite this css as xpath

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

How can I rewrite this css as xpath above from this [website](https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F436/S1/) using similar logic?

Original css:

```
.gl-Market_HasLabels + .gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333   .gl-ParticipantOddsOnly_Odds
```

I tried:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_HasLabels')]  +  //div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333')]//div[contains(@class, 'gl-ParticipantOddsOnly')]
```

These xpaths work but not when I combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_HasLabels')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333')]//div[contains(@class, 'gl-ParticipantOddsOnly')]
```

Note that `+` in CSS selector means *immediate next sibling*. `following-sibling` in XPath returns *all following siblings*, but Selenium code, e.g `driver.find_element_by_xpath(...)`, will return you the first one (required)

or you can explicitly set index of sibling that you want to find:

```
.../following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333')][1]//...
```

Note that in XPath indexation starts from `1`, not `0`

Comment: The original css gives 3 values where as that similar xpath gives 9 values.  I will test with printing xpath but in chrome inspect that happens :)